# Visual studio installation in Sharepoint 2016 Multi Server farm

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am having Sharepoint 2016 on-premise environment in Multi Server Farm. I want to create custom solutions using Visual Studio 2015 and Infopath. Could someone tell me on which server I should install visual studio, Infopath ie. in Application server or Front end server or both?

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

Do not install Visual Studio or any other tools on the production environment. You can set-up a new development environment for this purpose.

InfoPath is an office component and also do not install office on the production environment. You can create custom list forms using InfoPath on client computers.

Comment: Do you mean I need to create a development environment with all sharepoint multi server farm installed, visual studio installed in it seperately to work on it? Also want to know the reasons why it is not recommended to install on production environment?

Comment: Yes, I mean this but you don't need to set up all multi-server farm. You can set up only one database server and one frontend server SharePoint installed for the development environment and you can use this new development environment for development purposes. Actually, I don't develop server-side components on SharePoint. I prefer to develop client-side components using javascript API and REST API.

Comment: SharePoint is a great product which is based on .Net framework and should be updated by SharePoint admins. If you install other tools based on .Net framework on SharePoint environment, that tools can replace some .dll files or other components that SharePoint farm needs to run properly. Even if it seems like there isn't any problem after installing VS on SharePoint servers, that does not mean there won't be any problem.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. It is really helpful. one of my requirement is to capture the submitted custom list form details and send it to database in different server based on its level of approvals. Can I achieve this functionality only with Clientside components in my on-premise environment? If so could you please explain the approach?

Comment: I don't know your business requirements but If you don't need any custom logic on your form, you can connect your database table and SharePoint list directly using External Content Types. They are really useful when you need to  create a simple form to your database table. https://lightningtools.com/bcs/creating-an-external-content-type-with-sharepoint-designer-2013/